# How to combine list of items and possible attributes into a summary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of assets:

```
 id | name      | cateogoryid
----+-----------+-------------    
  1 | Asset One |           1    
  2 | Asset Two |           2
```

I then have a table of category attributes (possible attributes exhibited by assets in the category)

```
 id | name            | cateogoryid
----+-----------------+-------------
  1 | Attribute One   |           1
  2 | Attribute Two   |           1
  3 | Attribute Three |           1
  4 | Attribute One   |           2
  5 | Attribute Two   |           2
```

Finally, I have a table that links assets with attributes (shows which assets exhibit which attributes)

```
id | assetid | attributeid
----+---------+-------------
  1 | 1       |           1
  2 | 1       |           3
  3 | 2       |           5
```

And I want to convert this data into a table that shows a true/false value for each attribute for each asset:

```
 asset     | attribute       | result
-----------+-----------------+--------
 Asset One | Attribute One   |  true
 Asset One | Attribute Two   |  false
 Asset One | Attribute Three |  true
 Asset Two | Attribute One   |  false
 Asset Two | Attribute Two   |  true
```

I did some research on this but struggled to find any relevant examples as I didn't really know what to search for.

Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the query but something like this will get you started..

```
SELECT asset.name,
       attribute.name,
       CASE WHEN asset_attribute.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' else 'false' END AS result
FROM asset 
CROSS JOIN attribute 
LEFT JOIN asset_attribute
ON asset.id = asset_attribute.assetid
WHERE asset.categoryId = attribute.categoryId
```

Comment: For your current data `INNER Join` might work but later as you'll add data to attribute table it might not show correct result. See updated answer to allow `CROSS Join` in query.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e2172/7/0). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try along:

```
SELECT
  Asset.name asset
  , Attribute.name attribute
  , CASE WHEN (SELECT id FROM Asset_Attribute WHERE Asset_Attribute.assetID = Asset.id AND Asset_Attribute.attributeID = Attribute.id) IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END result
FROM Asset
INNER JOIN Attribute
  ON Asset.categoryID = Attribute.categoryID
ORDER BY Asset.id, Attribute.id;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2172/3/0)

I've to confess, though, I do not completely follow your setup. But this might be due to the provided being just part of a larger context.